# Using variables in multiple functions in SF

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

How can I use the same variable value in multiple places within the same component?

So how can I declare `var val ='something';` once and use it in multiple functions inside this component.

```
({
   doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
       var val ='something';
       //rest of the code...
   },
   something: function(cmp, event, helper) {
       var val ='something';
       //rest of the code...
   },
   another: function(cmp, event, helper) {
       var val ='something';
       //rest of the code...
   }
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Lightning Aura component, the place to store state is in component attributes.

You'd need to declare a component attribute in your markup, assign it a default value there or in `doInit()`, and then access or mutate that value in other functions.

Aura attributes are documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_attributes.htm).